# Why arrays needs dimension set at define time?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am just wondering, why can't we just define something like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[];
arr[0] = 1;
```

Like a list, to resize automatically.
What i want to know is why is this impossible and we need to set every time the size in the following way:

```
int[] arr = new int[1];
arr[0] = 1;
```

Comment: Well, because that's the way arrays work. They are defined by the language as fixed size containers.

Comment: @mehow I find it a quite interesting question. The answer "because the C#/CLR spec says so" doesn't do it justice, as you remarked yourself. The attempt to do so, especially when comparing to C++'s arrays and vectors, gave me new insights.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I partially agree the concept of the question itself is interesting but the question written is poor and doesn't give us a clue about the OPs skills. It's too broad to answer in my opinion. We don't know the OP's skill level so it's hard to explain why it's this way starting completely from scratch. A proper answer could be as long as a short book therefore I don't think this question is anwerable in its current format. Answers like 'because specs say so' indicate I am dealing with [programmers who can't program](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/)

Comment: @Peter Schneider I agree.  It's a 'stupid question' that many don't know the answer to, and as such is brilliant intentionally or otherwise.  Even my ponderings merely work with the limited information available.

Comment: @mehow then answer the challenge and provide an answer better than 'the specs say so.'  I'm happy to learn more about this question.

Comment: If you haven't already read it, I'd recommend taking a look at Eric Lippert's article [Arrays Considered Somewhat Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

`List<T>`'s resizing is based on creating a new array behind the scenes when it needs to.

Think about what the underlying implementation looks like here. When you allocate an array, it reserves a chunk of memory, and the reference effectively points straight at that memory. If you need to store more values than you've reserved, you need to allocate more memory, somewhere else... but you can't change the reference to refer to that new memory, because those references are spread all over the place. (The array doesn't know what's referring to it.)

The obvious way around this is to have a level of indirection - so that the initial reference is to an object which keeps track of where the *real* data is stored, so it can reallocate when it wants to. That's exactly what `List<T>` does... but it does mean there's that extra level of indirection. That has a cost in efficiency, partly as you may well have the actual data a long way in memory from the `List` object itself, which isn't good for caching... *and* simply going through an extra level of indirection has a cost in itself.

Basically if you *want* a dynamically sized collection, use `List<T>` - that's what it's there for. If you know the final size from the start and want to benefit from the "nearer to the metal" aspect of arrays, use those instead.

Arrays are a relatively low level concept - if you want a high level abstraction, use one...

Comment: Perhaps we should stress what you said implicitly -- that it is an efficiency issue. The indirection in List _can_ be costly overall in an inner loop somewhere. I assume that an array element access can be made as efficient as a C array access by the JIT in many situations, while I assume that access to a List element in most situations cannot. So C# (or CLR) could have been designed to have dynamic arrays, like many script languages do, but at the cost of being slower at runtime.

Comment: The allocated memory for arrays is contiguous? Even if this is true, why the compiler does not move the array in a free place and let me to do this? The result is the same at the end and when i do this i might raise some errors.

Comment: @liviupopovici: Yes, it's contiguous. If you don't care about contiguity, use a `LinkedList<T>`. I don't know what you mean by "move the array in a free place" - how can it move the array when there are lots of variables referring to the existing place? That's the point - if you need to cope with the data moving around, you need an extra level of indirection, which has a cost associated with it. An array is a relatively low-level type... if you want a high level abstraction, don't use an array!

Comment: Another question, and you are probably one of the best persons to ask: I'm under the impression that the Java runtime actually _does_ "secretly" move objects around due to garbage collection/compaction, and consequently needs to identify and update all their references. Is that so? Does the CLR not do that? (Wouldn't that lead to terrible heap fragmentation?) The information and control both runtimes have about/over objects seems similar. Is there a difference because C# allows unsafe code (whose pointers etc. would then potentially lack the needed runtime information)?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Yes, both Java and the CLR will move objects around. This involves a fair amount of coordination of course, in order to make sure that references are updated effectively atomically... it's not the sort of thing you'd want escaping into "I'm just adding to a collection".

Comment: In one of Wouter de Kort's books, he states that all threads are frozen while objects are being marked/compacted.

Comment: I was asking that because then I don't understand why scattered references to the array would preclude a re-allocation (the references would simply be updated behind the scenes, like after a gc run).-- Oh, I see what you said: Too expensive for everyday purposes.

Comment: @dcastro: I think these days a fair amount can happen *without* stop-the-world requirements... but that at some point you *may* need to stop everything, in some cases. I'm not a GC expert, but I know there have been many advances on both the CLR and JVM.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: The point is that you don't want that co-ordination (checking the whole heap for any references to the array!) every time someone adds an item to a collection.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, that's what I would expect.

Answer (score 7):

Because arrays are contiguous in memory, you have to allocate enough memory for its contents when you create it.

Say you have an array with 100 items in it. Now you add 1 more, and you have to claim the memory address right after the 100th item. What if that address is already being used?

That's why you can't dynamically resize an array.

Comment: But then you have all kinds of containers in C# which do resize happily, some of them contiguous as well (List). So what's the difference? The OP's question could perhaps been reworded to "why are there arrays at all?", given the broad functional overlap between arrays and Lists. (The answer was given by Jon Skeet and the ensuing discussion.)

Comment: I think that's a follow-up question, not the main question. But my answer would be - they're different levels of abstraction. That's the same thing as asking, why do we need a `Queue<T>` when we already have a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`? Different levels of abstraction.

Comment: Arrays are there because sometimes, that's all you need - you don't need any of the fancy stuff a `List<T>` gives you. They also serve a building block for most other collections.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be 'because it's specified this way' - which happens gives arrays specific performance characteristics and optimisation capabilities which are highly desirable.  While these advantages would have been noted by the designers, and be present in influencing languages which also use similar constructs (C, C++, Java - Footnote 1), they honestly could have defined it to do *anything*.

`List<T>` for example, has to resize the internal array usually allocating more memory than necessary (unless you happen to use just as much as been allocated) as well as creating garbage.

[1.8 of the C# language specification has the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

> An array is a data structure that contains a number of variables that
> are accessed through computed indices. The variables contained in an
> array, also called the elements of the array, are all of the same
> type, and this type is called the element type of the array.
>
> Array types are reference types, and the declaration of an array variable
> simply sets aside space for a reference to an array instance. Actual
> array instances are created dynamically at run-time using the new
> operator. ***The new operation specifies the length of the new array
> instance, which is then fixed for the lifetime of the instance.*** The
> indices of the elements of an array range from 0 to Length - 1. The
> new operator automatically initializes the elements of an array to
> their default value, which, for example, is zero for all numeric types
> and null for all reference types.

Furthermore, not mentioned by anyone-else array bounds checking is considered a 'software engineering principle' - as stated when describing their design goals in [the ECMA 334 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf):

> The language, and implementations thereof, should provide support for
> software engineering principles  such as strong type checking, **array
> bounds checking**, detection of attempts to use uninitialized variables,
> and automatic garbage collection. Software robustness, durability, and
> programmer productivity are  important.

[Footnote 1 - Introduction of C# language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

> C# (pronounced “See Sharp”) is a simple, modern, object-oriented, and
> type-safe programming language. C# has its roots in the C family of
> languages and ***will be immediately familiar to C, C++, and Java
> programmers.***

Comment: @mwhow, and *why* is it this way?  Do you know?  John skeet's answer points to implementation, as does mine, but they could have implemented it differently if they desired.

Comment: *`will be immediately familiar to C, C++, and Java programmers.`* that is completely off-topic. [Arrays in C# vs. C, Java etc are actually a bit different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @Mehow, Rather than being completely off-topic, it's a key design goal of C#.  Are C, C++ or Java non-fixed length?  Note:  'Familiar' != 'Identical'.

Answer (score 1):

That is because arrays allocate memory, and the framework needs to know how much.

If you want a dynamic sizing 'array', use `List`.

A list actually wraps an array. When adding more items then in current array, a new array (usually double sized) is created, old items are moved to the new array. Deleting goes the other way around.

Comment: OP wants to know why.

Comment: @Sam, "because the spec says so"? Seriously, this is akin to ask "why are ints 32-bits wide?". The language just works like that.

Answer (score 1):

Because an array's size is static by defintion and not dynamic.

If you want a dynamically sized collection, there are others, like the list you mentioned, available.

What you can do though is to delay the declaration of the size of the array:

```
int[] numbers;
numbers = new int[10];  
numbers = new int[20];
```

Comment: OP wants to know why.